# Is there an adjoint functor to the contravariant hom functor in the category of A-modules.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, category-theory

I should start by saying that I don't know any category theory. However, I am reading Atiyah-MacDonald and have just learned that in the category of A-modules (where here A is a commutative unital ring) the functor $\,H=$ Hom$(N,\cdot\,)$ is the right adjoint of the functor $\,T=\cdot\,\otimes_A N;$ that is:

Hom$(T(M),P)\cong$ Hom$(M,H(P))$ for all $A$-modules $M$ and $P.$

This leaves me with two questions:

1) What about tensoring on the left? I guess this is just the same since there is a canonical isomorphism between $N\otimes_A M$ and $M\otimes_A N$...?

2) Is there an adjoint for the contravariant hom functor Hom$(\cdot\,,N)?$

Many thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1) That's right.

2) It's adjoint to itself! This phenomenon is reasonably common for contravariant functors. $$\text{Hom}(A,\text{Hom}(B,C))\cong \text{Hom}(A\otimes B,C)\cong \text{Hom}(B\otimes A,C)\cong \text{Hom}(B,\text{Hom}(A,C))$$
Note that it's not well defined which copy of $\text{Hom}(-,C)$ is the right and which the left adjoint here; instead we tend to say the functor is self-adjoint on the right.

Comment: Great - thanks! :)