# Is there an adjoint functor to the hom bifunctor in the category of $R$-modules, $R$ is commutative unital ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, category-theory

I've seen that for $W\in R-\mathrm{\!Mod}$ ,both $\mathrm{Hom}(W,-)$ and $\mathrm{Hom}(-,W)$  have adjoint functors.

[adjoint of Hom(-,W)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1778833/is-there-an-adjoint-functor-to-the-contravariant-hom-functor-in-the-category-of)

this leaves me with one question:

$C:= R-\mathrm{\!Mod}$

does $\mathrm{Hom}(-,-):C^{op}\times C \to C$ have an adjoint functor?

Comment: It does not. It doesn't even preserve direct sums.

Comment: But it preserves limits since yoneda embedding preserves.

Comment: you are right， both side preserve sum does not mean that it preserve two-side sum(direct product).$F(A \times A',B\times B') \cong F(A,B \times B') \times F(A',B \times B')
$(the $A\times A'$is product in $C^{op}$, or coproduct in $C$)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A functor between additive categories which has either a left or a right adjoint must be additive, but $\text{Hom}$ is not; it is bilinear rather than linear. The tensor bifunctor also fails to have an adjoint for the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

I found a counterexample:

$C:= \mathrm{\mathbb{Z}-Mod}, D:=C^{op}\times C$

$R(-):=Hom(-,-) : D\to C$ , $L$ is the left adjoint of $R$.

Then $Hom_D(L(-),-)\cong Hom_C(-,R(-)):C^{op}\times D\to Set$

$\mathbb{Z}_i := \mathbb{Z}/i\mathbb{Z}$

$Hom_D(L(\mathbb{Z}_r),(\mathbb{Z}_n,\mathbb{Z}_m))\cong Hom_C(\mathbb{Z}_r,R(\mathbb{Z}_n,\mathbb{Z}_m))$

Suppose $L(\mathbb{Z}_r)=(M,N) \in D$

$Hom_D((M,N),(\mathbb{Z}_n,\mathbb{Z}_m))\cong Hom_{C^{op}}(M,\mathbb{Z}_n)\times Hom_D(N,\mathbb{Z}_m)\cong Hom_{C}(\mathbb{Z}_n,M)\times Hom_D(N,\mathbb{Z}_m)$

$|Hom_C(\mathbb{Z}_r,Hom(\mathbb{Z}_n,\mathbb{Z}_m)|=gcd(r,n,m)$

$|Hom_{C}(\mathbb{Z}_n,M)|\times |Hom_D(N,\mathbb{Z}_m)|=gcd(r,n,m)$

take n, we get $|Hom_D(N,\mathbb{Z}_m)|$ must be $1$.

by the same way $|Hom_{C}(\mathbb{Z}_n,M)|=1$

we have $gcd(r,n,m)=1$ for all n,m , that leads contradiction.

(I'm not sure whether I made a mistake or not)